# How to reuse a function within a python module

Tags: python, function, module

Im trying to reuse a function within another function of a Python module im writing. My search only reveals the same tutorial over and over again on how to write and use simple modules.

What I'm trying to do:

**module.py:**

```
def func1(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def func2(num1, num2, num3):
    return func1(num1, num2) * num3
```

**main.py**

```
import module as mod

num1 = 1
num2 = 2
num3 = 3

res = mod.func2(num1, num2, num3)
```

But this throws a NameError:
`NameError: name 'func1' is not defined`

I think this happens because `func1` from `module.py` has not been loaded in the kernel, but I don't know how to solve this without using `from module import *` which I really want to avoid.

Is there a way to reference `func1` from within `func2`? Or any other way to specify, that `func2` should load and use `func1`?

Comment: Use `import module as mode` and not `import module.py as mod`, that was giving me the `ModuleNotFindError`, I was not getting the NameError on running the code

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my script which i just couldn't see. Thanks for your help! Also I've removed the *.py ending on the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked without any problems with Ubuntu default Python 2.7

```
from module import func2
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
num3 = 3
res = func2(num1, num2, num3)
res
9
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Sorry. Had a typo in my script... Thanks for helping me!